# Getting AD Group Membership ADSI using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, adsi

I currently have ADSI code to get the groups a user is a part of:

```
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)"
$searcher.FindOne().Properties.memberof
$adgroups = $User -Replace '^cn=([^,]+).+$', '$1'
```

However, i am wanting to be able to choose a group and see its members. I currently have this code to get their DN and path.

```
$Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://cn=Test,cn=Test,dc=some,dc=domain,dc=net"
$Members = $Group.Member | ForEach-Object {[ADSI]"LDAP://$_"}
```

I am wanting to get other attributes if possible (name, etc.). Any help would be appreciated as i have been trying for a bit.

Comment: `[adsi]"LDAP://<dn>"` or `[adsi]"LDAP://server/<dn>"` should already give you the AD object including its attributes. Are you using ADSI for a particular reason? The `ActiveDirectory` module is usually a lot more convenient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already have both pieces, the first piece is finding the users in the group, the second piece is using the searcher to get properties for the users. Just use `distinguishedname` as the `[adsisearcher]` filter.

```
$Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://cn=Test,cn=Test,dc=some,dc=domain,dc=net"
$Group.Member | ForEach-Object {
    $Searcher = [adsisearcher]"(distinguishedname=$_)"
    $searcher.FindOne().Properties
}
```