# Map network drive with current users AD Group membership

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to map network drive for user if the user belongs to particular group say SSF. The share path is saved in the description field of each SSF group. I am not sure how to get the description field using ADSI searcher instead of get-adgroup since most of the user workstation does not have AD module installed. Any help will be appreciated.

```
group = ([ADSISEARCHER]"samaccountname=$($env:USERNAME)").Findone().Properties.memberof -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'
foreach ( $groups in $group)
{
if ($groups -like "*-User-SSF-*")
{
$SSFgroup = Get-ADgroup -Properties * -filter {name -like $groups} | Select-object Name, description, info
$TestPath = get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | Select-Object -expand DeviceID -Last 1 | ForEach-Object { [char]([int][char]$_[0]  + 1) + $_[1] }
$drive = $TestPath.Substring(0,1)
$DrivePath = $SSFgroup.description
write-output $DrivePath, $drive

If ((Get-PSDrive).displayRoot -eq $DrivePath) {
write-host "path exist"
}
else
{

New-PSDrive -Name $Drive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $DrivePath -Persist -Scope Global -ErrorAction Continue
}}}
```

Comment: You don't need AD module to map a drive. Either use `New-PSDrive` or you can use the old command line method of `NET USE`

Comment: Thanks. But i want to check if the user is part of *SSF* group and map the drive by reading the description of the group where the path are stored. I have more than 100 department where each group has name like "admin-SSF", Sales-SSF"  with share path stored in the description.

Comment: I'd suggest using [Group Policy](https://networkproguide.com/using-group-policy-to-map-network-drives/) for this.

Comment: i need help with getting group description field using adsi searcher option. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First issue, you are missing a `$` on `Group` - assuming that's a typo. Second thing, you assign to singular variable, and then iterate plural? Finally, it looks like you got this code from [Getting AD Group Membership ADSI using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351476/getting-ad-group-membership-adsi-using-powershell)  Why didn't you read the answer? I've taken the answer from that page and modified your code with it to achieve the desired comparison.

```
$groups = ([ADSISEARCHER]"samaccountname=$($env:USERNAME)").Findone().Properties.memberof

foreach ( $group in $groups)
{
    $groupinfo = ([adsisearcher]"(distinguishedname=$group)").FindOne().Properties

    if ($groupinfo.description -like "*-User-SSF-*")
    {
        $TestPath = get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | Select-Object -expand DeviceID -Last 1 | ForEach-Object { [char]([int][char]$_[0]  + 1) + $_[1]}
        $drive = $TestPath.Substring(0,1)
        $DrivePath = $groupinfo.description
        write-output $DrivePath, $drive

        If ((Get-PSDrive).displayRoot -eq $DrivePath)
        {
            write-host "path exist"
        }
        else
        {
            New-PSDrive -Name $Drive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $DrivePath -Persist -Scope Global -ErrorAction Continue
        }
    }
}
```