# Powershell output items of a string in an array to a file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

when i do a `net group (the name of the group) /domain` in powershell I get a list like this. Multiple items in a row with many white spaces in between:

```
groupmemberOne           groupmemberTwo           groupmemberThree
groupmemberFour          groupmemberFive          groupmemberSix
```

I want to extract/transform the output of `net group` and send it to a txt file via a script in the following format:

```
groupmemberOne
groupmemberTwo  
groupmemberThree
groupmemberFour
groupmemberFive     
groupmemberSix
```

what i did so far:

```
New-Item -Path "thepath and .txt file" -ItemType File -Force
$data = net group /domain (the name of the group)
$transform = $data[8..$($data.Count -3)]
$result = $transform | ConvertFrom-String | out-string
Add-Content -Value $transform -Path "thepath and .txt file"
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I think it will be better to use native PowerShell cmdlets instead of CMD tools. Have you tried using [Get-LocalGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @Olaf, a PowerShell-native solution is definitely better, but note that the question is about _domain_ groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:

- Generally, it's **better to use *PowerShell* commands**, so you don't have to rely on parsing *text* and can operate *objects* and their properties: see **[`Get-ADUserGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember)**; in the *simplest* case (doesn't distinguish between members of type user, computer, and group):

  ```
  (Get-ADUserGroupMember $groupName).Name > $outFile
  ```
- If you don't have the [`ActiveDirectory` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/) installed / cannot install it, you can use the **`[adsi]` class** (short for: [`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry)), as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) recommends:

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45353275/45375) for an example.
  - For information about the LDAP-query syntax required for use with `[adsi]`, see [this TechNet doc](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx).

---

If you want to stick with your text-parsing approach, use the unary form of the **[`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)** to parse the output from your `net.exe group` call, which splits strings by runs of whitespace, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace:

```
# ...
-split $transform > $outFile
```

Caveat: This won't work **if the group member names themselves contains space**. If they do, you'd have to split by runs of *multiple* spaces, under the assumption that such runs are exclusive to the whitespace *separating* the names:

```
# ... 
$transform -split '  +' > $outFile # split by 2 or more spaces
```

<sup>Note: `>` is an effective alias of `Out-File`, which means that in *Windows PowerShell* you'll get a "Unicode"-encoded file (UTF-16LE). If that is undesired, pipe to `| Set-Content -Encoding utf8 $outFile`, for instance.</sup>

To illustrate with simple examples that simulate the relevant part of `net group`'s output:

```
PS> -split (
     'groupmemberOne           groupmemberTwo           groupmemberThree',
     'groupmemberFour          groupmemberFive          groupmemberSix'
    )

groupmemberOne
groupmemberTwo
groupmemberThree
groupmemberFour
groupmemberFive
groupmemberSix
```

```
PS> (
     'groupmember One           groupmember Two           groupmember Three',
     'groupmember Four          groupmember Five          groupmember Six'
    ) -split '  +'

groupmember One
groupmember Two
groupmember Three
groupmember Four
groupmember Five
groupmember Six
```